# Convert String To Time (Only Hour and Minute)

Tags: php, mysql

I've done many research in google about this but didn't get result fit with this problem.

All i want just convert this string into time(mysql).

So the example format was like this :

```
$time = "15:10";
```

How it was gonna supposed to do if i want to insert $time into mysql ?

Comment: use mysql function [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: Please give it more specific. How it was written in query ?

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE('15:10', '%H:%i')`

Comment: It comes : Call to undefined function str_to_date() in

Comment: What exactly is the situation? Do you want to time strings like "15:10", "14:33", "12:14" converted into seconds like an unix-timestamp?

Comment: If it can be done with that way, maybe i will do it. How it is gonna supposed to do if using unix timestamp ?

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( NOW() ,  '%H:%i' ) AS time_column
```

If your date is in string format, then you will have to convert it into datetime using STR_TO_DATE function.

If your string is like this:

```
5/16/2011 20:14 PM
```

you can convert it to datetime using this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('5/16/2011 20:14 PM', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i')
```

or this to format it like you want:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('5/16/2011 20:14 PM', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')
```

Comment: Did you read my question properly ? Its not like i'm not appreciate your answer but the opposite i'm gratefull. But it is not answered my question. I want to insert not to select. And especially the time is input manually. So that 'now' function isn't needed.

Comment: My bad... I'm sorry that I didn't read your question properly. 

I thought you just wanted to covert string into time in mysql. That is why I gave examples for converting str to date and converting date into required time format i.e. hh:mm.

I think you should add details about the destination table in which you are trying to insert. It will help everybody understand the problem statement better. 

Just want to help!!